# SymPy not solving equation involving a difference of log terms

Tags: sympy

```py
import sympy as sp
t, a, b, x, T, psi1 = sp.symbols('t a b x T psi_1')

eq = -T+ t+ sp.log((a+x)**(0.71/psi1)*(b+x)**-(0.71/psi1))-sp.log(a**(0.71/psi1)*(b**(-0.71/psi1)))

sp.solve(eq,x)
```

Comment: I don't think there is a symbolic solution to this equation. You may try `nsolve` if you know the values of the other parameters.

Comment: Thanks David (it had a symbolic solution, we derived it by hand but wanted to check if this can  be done with Sympy)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that solve can't handle this equation in its current form. If you simplify the equation a bit then it can:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sp
   ...: t, a, b, x, T, psi1 = sp.symbols('t a b x T psi_1')
   ...: 
   ...: eq = -T+ t+ sp.log((a+x)**(0.71/psi1)*(b+x)**-(0.71/psi1))-sp.log(a**(0.71/psi1)*(b**(-0.71/p
   ...: si1)))

In [2]: eq
Out[2]: 
            ⎛ 0.71  -0.71 ⎞      ⎛       0.71        -0.71 ⎞
            ⎜ ────  ──────⎟      ⎜       ────        ──────⎟
            ⎜  ψ₁     ψ₁  ⎟      ⎜        ψ₁           ψ₁  ⎟
-T + t - log⎝a    ⋅b      ⎠ + log⎝(a + x)    ⋅(b + x)      ⎠

In [3]: powsimp(eq, deep=True, force=True)
Out[3]: 
            ⎛   0.71⎞      ⎛       0.71⎞
            ⎜   ────⎟      ⎜       ────⎟
            ⎜    ψ₁ ⎟      ⎜        ψ₁ ⎟
            ⎜⎛a⎞    ⎟      ⎜⎛a + x⎞    ⎟
-T + t - log⎜⎜─⎟    ⎟ + log⎜⎜─────⎟    ⎟
            ⎝⎝b⎠    ⎠      ⎝⎝b + x⎠    ⎠

In [5]: solve(powsimp(eq, deep=True, force=True), x)
Out[5]: 
⎡                             100⋅ψ₁      ⎤
⎢                             ──────      ⎥
⎢                               71        ⎥
⎢             ⎛   0.71       ⎞            ⎥
⎢             ⎜   ────       ⎟            ⎥
⎢             ⎜    ψ₁        ⎟            ⎥
⎢             ⎜⎛a⎞      T - t⎟            ⎥
⎢       a - b⋅⎜⎜─⎟    ⋅ℯ     ⎟            ⎥
⎢             ⎝⎝b⎠           ⎠            ⎥
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────⎥
⎢                1.40845070422535⋅ψ₁      ⎥
⎢⎛   0.71       ⎞                         ⎥
⎢⎜   ────       ⎟                         ⎥
⎢⎜    ψ₁        ⎟                         ⎥
⎢⎜⎛a⎞      T - t⎟                         ⎥
⎢⎜⎜─⎟    ⋅ℯ     ⎟                    - 1.0⎥
⎣⎝⎝b⎠           ⎠                         ⎦
```